# SQL Query: do I need two queries or can I use a nested subquery

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This question may have been asked before but I don't really know what verbiage to search with.

I have a mysql DB that has a table with 3 columns [ID, fieldName and fieldValue] that is used to describe attributes of objects in another table. The ID field stores the foreign key of object in the other table and the fieldName and fieldValue store things like title, description, file size and summary.

I am trying to write a query that returns rows where a fieldName and fieldValue pair match known values and the returned row ID has a another distinct fieldValue in another row. Right now I am accomplishing it with two queries and an if statement. Here is the sudo code:

```
$result = SELECT * FROM table_a WHERE fieldName = 'title' and fieldValue = 'someTitle'
$test = SELECT * FROM table_a WHERE fieldValue = 'someValue' and id = '{$result['id']}'
if ($test) {
  /* Result Found */
}
```

Comment: Neither - Given the example you've shown you would never get any results. `table_a.fieldValue` cannot equal 'someTitle' and 'someValue' at the same time.

Please show actual examples to get help. You may need a join, or simply a basic query, depending on what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: fieldName and fieldValue are two different columns, they can both have distinct values at the same time

Comment: But fieldValue is used twice. 

Look at the queries you wrote. You're essentially doing: `WHERE fieldName = 'title' and fieldValue = 'someTitle' and fieldValue = 'someValue'` which will NEVER return any rows. (`where a=1 and b=2 and b=3`) Hence, I suggest you show us some real values.

Comment: No, the two SQL statements are separate queries. The first is used to obtain the ID number and the second is used to see if records with that ID have a certain value in fieldValue.

Comment: Do you really not see the problem? Show us the REAL column names. I realize that you're running two queries. But if you select a row where fieldName = 'title' and fieldValue = 'someTitle' and let's say it's ID is 5. Then you select where id = 5 and fieldValue = 'someValue' you will NEVER GET A ROW BACK.

Comment: Those are the real column names. I think I see the confusion. There can be multiple records with the same ID since it is a foreign key from another table. So, you could have two records like ID=1, fieldName='title', fieldValue='American Pie' and ID=1, fieldName='Type', fieldValue='Movie'. In my query I want to find the record with title American Pie only if it also has a record with type=movie.

Comment: That still makes no sense, and it appears you are storing your data very poorly. You could still do it with a join, but you should just store the data the way a table should be set up - a column called type and in it, Movie. A column called title, and in it "American Pie". Not two rows for basic data.

Comment: The table design was done this way to store a constantly growing list  of specific attributes about a video without creating new columns on the videos tables for every possible attribute. I think it is fairly common practice to store key and name/value pairs in certain situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can self-join the table:

```
SELECT * FROM table_a AS s1 
JOIN table_a AS s2 USING (id)
WHERE
    s1.fieldName = 'Title' AND s1.fieldValue = 'someTitle'
    AND s2.fieldValue = 'someValue'
```

Answer (score 0):

What you said translated in sql would be:

```sql
SELECT b.* 
FROM table_a a
INNER JOIN table_a b ON a.id = b.id
WHERE a.fieldName = 'title'
  AND a.fieldValue = 'someTitle'
  AND a.fieldValue <> b.fieldValue
```

This gets you the rows in table_a that have the same id as the row with you predefined values, but with a different fieldValue. This assumes that id is not the primary key, otherwise there will not be another row with the same id, but it looks in your question that this isn't the case.  (If you want to check for a specific value you can do: `AND b.fieldValue = 'someValue'` in the last line)